# how can i retrieve 2 columns data from database using one cursor

Tags: android, database, cursor

how can i retrieve 2 columns data from database using one cursor....now i am using 2 cursors at a time  like

```
ArrayList<String> sender_array = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> body_array = new ArrayList<String>();


messagedb=ListView.this.openOrCreateDatabase("message",0, null);
    messagedb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab2(sender INT(13),body varchar)");

Cursor  cur1=mydb.rawQuery("select * from tab2", null);

    while(cur.moveToNext())
    {
        String sender1=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("sender"));
                    sender_array.add(sender1);
    }
    cur1.close();
Cursor  cur2=mydb.rawQuery("select * from tab2", null);

    while(cur.moveToNext())
    {
        String body1=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
                    body_array.add(body1);
    }
    cur2.close();

    messagedb.close();
```

how can i use one cursor for poping out a list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor  cur=mydb.rawQuery("select sender, body from tab2", null);
while(cur.moveToNext())
{
    String sender = cur.getString(0);
    String body = cur.getString(1);
}
cur.close();
```

or this is safer, if you decide to change the columns order later

```
Cursor  cur=mydb.rawQuery("select sender, body from tab2", null);
while(cur.moveToNext())
{
    String sender = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("sender"));
    String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
}
cur.close();
```

Comment: how can i add this two strings in a list view

Comment: so how can i add this two values in a string and use further listview access

Comment: That would be a separate question. But you can pass the cursor to a SimpleCursorAdapter, and let the adapter retrieve the columns and update the list item. See here for an example: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Answer (score 0):

Use one Cursor as follows:

```
Cursor  cur=mydb.rawQuery("select sender, body from tab2", null);
```

**Update:**

You don't need an ArrayList, you can load the Cursor directly to a SimpleCursorAdapter and use this adapter to load the data to the ListView

```
SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

then set the adapter to the ListView:

```
ListView.setAdapter(your_SimpleCursorAdapter)
```

Comment: so how can i add this two values in a string and use further listview access

Comment: Check the updated answer, `layout` is a custom Layout you create to represent each row in the ListView, `from` are the column names (sender & body) and finally `to` is the Ids of the TextViews in `layout` that will put the `from` columns to.